# What is the English translation of Hanuman Chalisa?

Tags: hanuman, translation-request, book-recommendation, meaning, hanuman-chalisa

I have recited this Chalisa since I was a child and although I have understood the meaning of some parts of it, I would love to get the meaning of the entire prayer.

Here is the [full text](https://lyricsmouse.com/shree-hanuman-chalisa-lyrics/) for reference.

The language it is written in is Hindi, but anyone with knowledge of any English based language may be able to interpret it.

Comment: You can find it [here](https://www.hindutemplealbany.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Sri_Hanuman_Chalisa_English.pdf).

Comment: Basically  Bhakti  stotram along with narration of  achievements in Ramayana

Answer (score 4):

You can read Gita Press' English translation of Hanuman Chalisa [here](https://book.gitapress.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1528-Hanuman-chalisa27-x-17.pdf).

They have also made few other e-books available for free on [their website](https://book.gitapress.org/product-category/e-book/english-e-book/).

Answer (score 1):

In this [blog](https://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/chalisa/lord-hanuman/translation/english/shree-hanuman-chalisa-translation.html) you could read the verse by verse translation of Hanuman chalisa.

Answer (score 1):

here [Hanuman Chalisa](https://shrihanumanchalisa.in) you can check all types of chalisa and translation in kannada English Etc [Hanuman Chalisa kannada](https://shrihanumanchalisa.in/hanuman-chalisa-in-kannada-lyrics-pdf-download/) with meaning

[Bhutan winner](https://shrihanumanchalisa.in/bhutan-winner)